# Drush is updated but not usable in Drupal 8 in Windows

Tags: drush, 8

Is this a bug? I've the version that does support Drupal 8, so what is actually the problem here?

[image]

### Update

I followed kiamlaluno and seem to have updated Drush but I still get the same error. I haven't touched the settings.php file. It's a totally brand new site so I would still get an error :\

[image]

Comment: Drush is telling you it doesn't support Drupal 8. I would trust it.

Comment: The second error can also mean that drush is not able to find a working settings.php . Make sure drush knows what site to use ;)

Comment: You still have drush 7.x installed.

Comment: Hi @Pinoniq, how one should make sure such a thing? Why being in the site's folder won't be enough? Would thank you if you detail for the sake of others readers, and me,

Comment: Technicaly, you are not in a 'sites folder'. You are in the root of the drupal project. Drupal allows you to have multiple sites isntalled on the same code. So drush needs to know what 'site' to use. the default is in sites/default. But you should probably first fix the first problem where your drush version is not the correct one (as pointed out in the answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported in [Drupal Compatibility](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility), only Drush 8 and higher versions are compatible with Drupal 8. To be more exact, Drush 8 is compatible with Drupal 8.3 or previous versions, while Drush 9 (the master branch) is compatible with Drupal 8.4 or higher versions.

```
Drush Version   Drush Branch    PHP     Compatible Drupal versions
Drush 9         master          5.6+    D8.4+         
Drush 8         8.x             5.4.5+  D6, D7, D8.3- 
Drush 7         7.x             5.3.0+  D6, D7        Unsupported
Drush 6         6.x             5.3.0+  D6, D7        Unsupported
Drush 5         5.x             5.2.0+  D6, D7        Unsupported
```

<sub><sup>[Copy of the table taken from Drush documentation on October 24, 2018]</sup></sub>

When this answer was written, Drupal 8.4 didn't exist, and Drush 8 (the master branch at the time) was compatible with every Drupal 8 release existing at that time.

Since you are using Drush 7, you are using a version that is not compatible with Drupal 8 (and it's not even supported anymore). To install Drush master as global Composer package, you need to run the following command.

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master --prefer-source
```

On OS X, if you have Homebrew installed, you just need to run the following command, which would install Drush 8.

```
brew install drush
```

After I do that, `drush --version` returns me the following.

> Drush Version   :  8.0.0

On Windows, the [Drush documentation](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/) suggests:

- Use [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/downloads)
- Run Linux/OSX via Virtualbox

You probably need to first remove Drush 7.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I don't know what is OS X, I use Windows 10 home. I've tried to run the first version of your solution and it seems it ran but the problem persist... It's saddens me very much. Please see my update in the question. Would mean much to me,

Comment: OS X is the Apple's operating system.

Comment: It persists because it is still using Drush 7.

Comment: The Drush docs are a bit outdated. Instead of `master`, `8.0.x` should be used. The latest release is `8.0.1`.

Comment: But why do you think the update I tried to make via your instructions didn't work? Please help dear @kiamlaluno,

Comment: @benos You are still getting the _Drush 7.0.0 doesn't support Drupal 8_ message, which means you are still executing Drush 7.0; try _drush status_ and you will see it.

Comment: Yea when I wrote "drush status" this same error appeared. I just ask myself why when I tried to update --- The update didn't come to pass as in the picture I added? Maybe I should just uninstall and then reinstall Drush with a newer version.

Comment: @benos That is why I wrote _You probably need to first remove Drush 7_.

Answer (score 6):

You need drush 8 for drupal 8. You have drush 7 installed.

Comment: Which is wrong now. Now you need Drush 9 for Drupal 8. Check http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility

Answer (score -1):

Please, use as simple as:
`composer require "drush/drush:^9.0"`
in folder within composer.json